# Convert String to UTF-8 in PHP

Tags: php, html, utf-8, character-encoding, sms

I collect a string from an HTML form, and pass it to an external SMS API that converts everything to UTF-8. I have a real hard time with random special characters displaying weird after the conversion. I have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` set in the html header, I have tried `accept-charset="UTF-8"` in the form element and various other MBDETECT, ICONV functions with no luck. For Example:

```
$text = "¢";
$new = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $text);
echo $new;
echo utf8_encode($new);
```

The cent sign always ends up looking like : Â¢ after being re-encoded to UTF-8 by the extrenal api I use no matter what I try. This is just code I use for testing. If utf8_encode() echos out ¢ instead of Â¢, my problem is solved. The result is fine in html, The problem is it is being sent via SMS so when they receive the text message, the symbol looks like Â¢ instead of ¢

Comment: Your server serves the page using some other encoding?

Comment: It is a public html form, so people are creating the string, not my server

Comment: Yes, but what you see is a page your server puts out.

Comment: No, the end result is what an external API puts out after encoding to UTF-8. So basically I need ¢ to return as ¢ after being encoded to UTF-8 by the API, but it is being returned as Â¢. For testing on my end, I use utf8_encode(). The cent sign is just an example, the problem exists with multiple symbols

Comment: as far as I understand, you have tried a lot of html header configuration in the HTML-Page of the formular.
You echo the encoded result via PHP back to the Browser, right? So have you used the same html-header for this "result"-page? So is the Result valid HTML with all that utf-8 stuff?

Comment: The result is fine in html, The problem is it is being sent via SMS so when they receive the text message, the symbol looks like Â¢ instead of ¢

Comment: Please put that last comment of yours to the question too, and add an appropriate tag for SMS.

Comment: It looks like UTF-8 is not necessarily the encoding system of the [SMS messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS#Message_size).

Comment: I added that comment to the question. They definitely use UTF-8 encoding, as the result of  utf8_encode() is exactly the same as the SMS output. They also specify UTF-8 in their api documentation.